# Restkit mapping 0.2

Tags: ios, ipad, restkit

How to map a `json` like this in Restkit 2.0.I can't find a tutorial and all tutorials there is for previous versions.I know how it is done in 0.10.0 but dont have an idea how to do this array and nested arrays in 0.20.0

```
 {
      "days" : [
        {
          "day" : 1,
          "id" : 1,
          "set1" : [
            {
              "exercise_id" : 1,
              "exerciseunits" : [
                {
                  "count" : 3,
                  "id" : 1,
                  "weight" : 60
                }
              ],
              "id" : 1,
              "name" : null,
              "subbodypart_id" : 1,
              "subbodypartname" : "Chest"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "description" : "desc",
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "asdfg"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the updated [documentation in the wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) about object mapping. More than that you can download the current RestKit master with examples (e.g. Twitter Core Data) where nested objects are used as well.